# Android Volley Kotlin: (Mutable)Map<(raw) Any?, (raw) Any?>! vs MutableMap<String, String>

Tags: android, dictionary, kotlin, android-volley

In Android with Kotlin and Volley Library, I am using the below code to put a map into jsonObject.

```kotlin
val params = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
params["key1"] = "value1"
params["key2"] = "value2"
val parameter = JSONObject(params)
```

This give me the below error:

```
Java type mismatch expected (Mutable)Map<(raw) Any?, (raw) Any?>! but found MutableMap<String, String>. Use explicit cast
```

1. Why do I need explicit cast as `params as Map<*, *>`
2. What is (Mutable)Map?
3. What are differences between (Mutable)Map and MutableMap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `JSONObject` constructor takes a `Map` with raw types (the generics are not specified).  As such you should supply a map that can be of `Any` type :

```
val params = mutableMapOf<Any?, Any?>()
    params["key1"] = "value1"
    params["key2"] = "value2"
    val parameter = JSONObject(params)
```

The warning `(Mutable)Map<(raw) Any?, (raw) Any?>` is showing the Java parameter argument - stating it can expect either a `Map` or `MutableMap`, as you are calling Java code from Kotlin - Java won't know if the `Map` is mutable or immutable.  Just to note raw types are not supported by Kotlin, you only encounter this problem if calling Java code.